# ColdFusion CFGrid: Validating Input via JQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, coldfusion, cfgrid

I have a CFGrid which allows editing of data. What I need to do is to validate user inputs via jQuery using some onblur or onchange events. But my jQuery code is unable to access the CFGrid elements using Classes. Here is a code snippet:

```
<td class=" x-grid-cell x-grid-cell-securityusers_ACTIVE   " id="ext-gen1066"><div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align: LEFT; ;" id="ext-gen1067">No</div></td>
```

The above code shows in Firebug when an editable cfgridcolumn is clicked in. So I should be able to use the following:

```
$('.x-grid-cell-securityusers_ACTIVE').click(function(){            
     alert('click') ;  
});
```

But this event never fires. I can confirm my jQuery load is fine because a container div (which holds the grid) would generate the click event.

My guess is that CFGRID, being dynamically generated, just doesn't register with JQuery; I have the javascript code also tried under a    `$(document).ready(function() {`  but still no event being fired.

Any ideas? Any alternate approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an html grid?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. It's html grid

Comment: Could be that you are trying to mix event models from two different libraries (ExtJS and jQuery). That is problematic at best.

Comment: You';re gonna have to read up on validation in ExtJS. jQuery and CFGRID are a bad mix. You've trying to have trigger document based events vs. ExtJS defined events, which define on the fly as content is rendered.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the ExtJS events in CFGRID; let me see them and remove jQuery from the code...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I think, per comments, the correct approach would have been to study the ExtJS APIs but I didn't have the time for that after some futile tries. So I ended up doing ColdFusion's own validations for the input data after the form post; a bit painful but it works.

Comment: Truthfully the UI components like cfgrid are bundled with very outdated versions of the underlying JS libs, and are difficult to customize. IMO the best option is to drop them altogether. Just use whatever JS library you want directly. That way you can use whatever version of the lib you want and not have to worry about things breaking when you update CF.

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, I'd recommend https://datatables.net/

Comment: Thank you both. I have some background in Datatables.net but they were for read-only tabular data and didn't see any 'examples' for ColdFusion for Edits. So, after maybe 12 years, I decided to give the CFGrid another try--only to find out it's so damn hard to configure. Anyway, I got most of the work done; if I knew the limitations of CFGrid, I would have started with jQuery approach. Adobe treats CF as a step child!